# All of my applications throw "deadline was exceeded". GAE breakdown?

Tags: google-app-engine

Do you have the same? How to recover my apps?

```
2016-05-17 14:13:33.887
Process terminated because the request deadline was exceeded. (Error code 123)
```

**It is not a duplicate** I guess it is something like a breakdown today. All of my app are dead at the same time. Even on production that were not updated this month.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to solve "Process terminated because the request deadline was exceeded. (Error code 123)" in google api?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30913255/how-to-solve-process-terminated-because-the-request-deadline-was-exceeded-err)

Comment: My apps are all up and running FYI

Comment: I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: I have the same issue, the app was working fine until one hour ago when a first request failed and all subsequent requests started to fail as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, there is even an issue for that. So I guess it is not only my problem.
https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/appengine/16005

> We are currently investigating an issue with App Engine that affects
>   applications connecting to Cloud SQL. We will provide more information
>   about the issue by 06:00 US/Pacific.

Comment: Same, multiple webpages using CloudSQL got 500 server error